# C program not functioning as expected when trying to iterate over multidimensional array to fill the rest of the array with calculated table values

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

In the code below, all variables (`startV`,`endV`,`volumeStep`,`tempStep`) are doubles that are pre-defined by user earlier on in the code.  The variable `rowNum` is an integer.  The program seems to break when it reaches `Table[j][i] = (nR*(Table[i][0]))/(Table[0][j]);` and tries to calculate and assign the value using the row and column already in the array.  I can't figure out what is going wrong.  Thanks for the help in advance :)  Oh yeah, and the array Table is initialized as `Table[rowNum][9];`

```
for (int i = 1;i<=8;i++) //Fills the Volume COLUMNS axis of the table [0][v]
{
    Table[0][i] = startV + (volumeStep*(i-1));
}



for (int i = 1;i<=rowNum;i++) //Fills the Temperature ROWS axis of the table  [t][0]
{
    Table[i][0] = startT + (tempStep*(i-1));
}



nR = moles*8.314;

for (int i = 1; i<=rowNum;i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j<=8; j++)
    {
        Table[j][i] = (nR*(Table[i][0]))/(Table[0][j]);
        printf("%lf", Table[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in c are indexed from `0` to `N - 1`, this for instance

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= rowNum ; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++)
```

so when you reach `i == rowNum` your program invokes undefined behavior

Or perhaps you should declare `Table` as

```
double Table[rowNum + 1][9];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Oh yeah, and the array Table is initialized as Table[rowNum][9];

Which means that this:

```
Table[j][i] = (nR*(Table[i][0]))/(Table[0][j]);
```

is wrong. You meant `Table[j][i]` as you loop your `i` from `1` to `rowNum` and your `j` from `1` to `8`.

Also if your first array has `rowNum` elements you can only loop to `rowNum - 1` inclusive (the last element).

Comment: He meant `Table[i][j]` presumably. Also `i` goes out of bounds on the last iteration.